# Most effective bracing arrangement for resisting seismic forces?

Tags: seismic

Which bracing arrangement is most effective for resisting seismic forces?

Answer (score 0):

X bracing generally is the strongest arrangement if this is what you meant "the most effective".

In plan layout, the center of rotation of the bracings shall be coincident, or as close as possible, with the center of rigidity of structure to avoid/minimize incidental torsion. Also, the bracings shall be provided as far from the center of rigidity as possible to resist the torsional effect, if any.

Comment: There was an interesting project done a while ago at Imperial College (London) studying ethnic building designs in high-earthquake regions in Asia. It turned out the most "successful" design patterns were actually the "floppiest." They moved a lot, but nothing actually broke.

Comment: High flexibility/ductility is desirable in seismic consideration if serviceability (comfortable of occupants) can be maintained during normal uses. The latest trend in the US is that, during the seismic event, damage to the structure is permitted, but a complete collapse. For steel building, the connection is the most critical item for design.